# AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'tags'

Tags: python, django, view, model

My views . this view contains error in news.tags

```
class NewsDetailView(DetailView):
model = News
template_name='news/detail_news.html'
context_object_name= 'news'


def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    news=News.objects.all()
    tags=news.tags.all()
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['comments'] = Comment.objects.filter(news=self.object)
    context['my_likes'] = Like.objects.filter(news=self.object)
    context['popular_news'] = news.order_by("-count")[:6]
    context['tags'] = tags
    # context["tags"] = TaggableManager().bulk_related_objects(self.object)
    self.object.count = self.object.count + 1
    self.object.save()
    return context
```

this is my models . i have created this to make a news . and i want to add tags in my news without TaggableManager()

```
class Tag(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=30)


class News(models.Model):
CATEGORY=(("0","Politics"),("1","Sports"),("2","Health"),("3","Business"),("4","International"),("5","Finance"))
title=models.CharField(max_length=250)
story= models.TextField()
count= models.IntegerField(default=0)
tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
video_url = models.URLField(max_length=270, null=True)  #makemigrations garna baki xa
category= models.CharField(choices=CATEGORY, max_length=2)
slug=models.SlugField(max_length=270,blank=True,null=True)
created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
cover_image=models.ImageField(upload_to="uploads")
author= models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
video_image = models.ImageField(null=True)

def get_absolute_url(self):

    return reverse("detail_news",kwargs={"category":self.get_category_display(), "pk":self.pk, "slug":self.slug})
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope help you:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    news=News.objects.all()
    tags=news.tags_set.all() <--edit
```

Comment: First, it should be `.tags.all()` instead of `tags_set.all()` because the model has `tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)`. Next, you can't call `news.tags.all()` for a queryset like `news`. You can only call it for a single object. We're in a `DetailView`, therefore you can use `self.objects.tags.all()`.